# XSL Grouping items by a tag not an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, grouping

I'm trying to work out how to use XSL to group an XML by the tag . Basically I want all the  records to output the A's first, then the B's, then the C's if they existed which they don't in this example.

```
<PAYSLIP>
 <RECORD.MISC>
  <EMP_ID>0009011</EMP_ID>
  <ITEM.MISC>
   <ID>1001</ID>
   <DESCRIPTION>First Job Pay</DESCRIPTION>
   <VALUE>1000</VALUE>
   <SOURCE>A</SOURCE>
  </ITEM.MISC>
  <ITEM.MISC>
   <ID>1001</ID>
   <DESCRIPTION>Second Job Pay</DESCRIPTION>
   <VALUE>500</VALUE>
   <SOURCE>B</SOURCE>  
  </ITEM.MISC> 
  <ITEM.MISC>
   <ID>1001</ID>
   <DESCRIPTION>Car Allowance</DESCRIPTION>
   <VALUE>50</VALUE>
   <SOURCE>A</SOURCE>  
  </ITEM.MISC> 
 </RECORD.MISC>
</PAYSLIP>
```

The output required is:

```
>A
>First Job Pay  1000
>Car Allowance  50
>B
>Second Job Pay 500
```

I can achieve this with the following XSL but can't work out how to use a for-each-group or key statement to do this? At present I am going to have to repeat this piece of code for each letter of the alphabet which is not very efficient so I would be keen to learn another way to do this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="ITEM.MISC[SOURCE='A']">
<tr><xsl:value-of select="SOURCE"/></tr>
<tr>
 <td class="description">
   <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
 </td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="value">
   <xsl:call-template name="formatnumber">
     <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/></xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="ITEM.MISC[SOURCE='B']">
<tr><xsl:value-of select="SOURCE"/></tr>
<tr>
 <td class="description">
   <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
 </td>
 <td></td>
 <td class="value">
   <xsl:call-template name="formatnumber">
     <xsl:with-param name="value"><xsl:value-of select="VALUE"/></xsl:with-param>
   </xsl:call-template>
 </td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I'm currently using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="PAYSLIP">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//ITEM.MISC" group-by="SOURCE">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/DESCRIPTION|current-group()/VALUE"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DESCRIPTION">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE">
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I shall study what you have done now to understand it.